# An `any` function for Data.Set

Tags: haskell

I need to check if any element of a set satisfies a predicate. So far I've been using lists, so I just used

```
any myPredicate sx
```

but using a set in my case is semantically more correct (and probably more efficient). However there's no `any` for sets, and I end up with lots of lines like this (`Data.Set as S`):

```
any myPredicate $ S.toList mySet
```

Is there a way not to litter my code with all those conversions, like with monoids or the like...?

(I mean, there must be a way besides defining `anyS p s = any p $ S.toList s`, otherwise why isn't it in `Data.Set`...?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about

```
import qualified Data.Set as Set
import           Data.Set (Set)

orS :: Set Bool -> Bool
orS = Set.foldr (||) False

anyS :: (a -> Bool) -> Set a -> Bool
anyS p = orS . Set.map p
```

or, even more simply, since a `Set` is `Foldable`

```
import qualified Data.Foldable as F

anyS :: (a -> Bool) -> Set a -> Bool
anyS = F.any
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import Data.Set (Set)
import qualified Data.Set as Set

anyS :: (a -> Bool) -> Set a -> Bool
anyS predicate s = not $ Set.null $ Set.filter predicate s
```